# get character before second underscore

Tags: r

How do I specify the **second** underscore in a string? I want to get the part before the second underscore.

```
    > head(colnames(counts))
[1] "1_JH_F12_S41.mature"   "107_MAE_E7_S11.mature" "108_IME_A8_S23.mature" "109_GW_B11_S27.mature"
[5] "111_PH_H1_S77.mature"  "116_TH_E6_S10.mature"
```

My try which gives string before the **first** underscore:

```
sub("_.*", "", colnames(counts))
```

out:

```
1_JH
107_MAE
...
```

Comment: see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26265400/use-regex-in-r-to-retrieve-string-before-second-occurence-of-a-period)

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7449564/regex-return-all-before-the-second-occurrence) is EXACTLY the same!

Comment: Right....The string is different...